# Why is my loop continuing past it's limit?

Tags: ruby

The inner loop seems to be working fine, but the outer loop goes past the 500 limit. Why is this?

```
Given("I save all emails") do
  emails = 0
  i = 1
  until emails == 500
      until i == 120
          fetch_emails(i, emails)
          i += 1
      end
      click_next_button
      emails += 120
      puts emails
      i = 1
      puts i
    end
end
```

Comment: cause emails += 120 and that counts to 120, 240, 360, 480, 600 etc

Comment: Can you see `500` in the list of values printed by `puts emails`? `until emails == 500` stops when `emails` is exactly `500`, no more, no less.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is `emails == 500`. This means that any number different than 500 will continue the loop. What you're trying to achieve however is `until emails >= 500`